# react app with hapi-react-views click not firing

Tags: reactjs, hapi.js

I have an issue with my button clicks not firing in my app.  I am trying to use React with a simple hapi server.  I have it rendering with the hapi-react-views node package.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?  Some code below.

```
const React = require('react');
import { Jumbotron, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class HomeView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.buttonClicked = this.buttonClicked.bind(this);
    }

    buttonClicked() {
        console.log('you clicked something');
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
            <Button onClick={this.buttonClicked} bsStyle="success">Test Button</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = HomeView;
```

Comment: Your code look fine, what are you trying to do ? Do you have errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`<Button onClick={() => this.buttonClicked} bsStyle="success">Test Button</Button>`